# Incorrect days-until-public count for private beta's login page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, private-beta

For example, Physics have just entered private beta, which have **7** days before entering public beta. However the [login page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/login) says "Warning: this site is currently in private beta for **5** more days".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am changing this to

> Warning: this site is currently in private beta for **at least** (x) more days.

That's because we've had several private betas go on for more than 7 days now...