# Inconsistent number of days remaining for private betas

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, private-beta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect days-until-public count for private beta's login page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69252/incorrect-days-until-public-count-for-private-betas-login-page)

A small nitpick, but the number of days remaining when you try to visit a site that's in private beta is not the same as the number of remaining when you visit its proposal on Area 51.

An off-by-one error, perhaps?

[image: on area 51]

[image: on the site in private beta]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems alright to me.

It is in *private* beta for 1 more day.
The day after it will be in *public* beta. (Add one day).

That makes two days for Public beta to begin.

Comment: You may have a point there, although according to the tooltip you get when you hover the number of days on Area 51, it says that the public beta opens Aug 30 at 19:00 UTC. Since we're already on Aug 29 UTC, that's tomorrow, or in 1 day.

Comment: In either case, the tooltip, while subtle, answered my question of when it _actually_ starts. Perhaps there should be a tooltip on the counter on the site itself as well?

Comment: @hammar yes, that should make things clearer.